# How to extract sub elements and text from XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have the following XML and I want to extract *everything* under the en-note element, including text and sub-elements, using Java and possibly XPath?

Source XML:

```
<en-note style="word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-nbsp-mode: space; -webkit-line-break: after-white-space;">
  A little test note…
  <div><br/></div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>blah</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</en-note>
```

What I want to extract:

```
  A little test note…
  <div><br/></div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>blah</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Thanks,

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/xpath.html ?

Comment: The problem with that is I can't find a way to grab sub-elements & the text in there.  I can only get one or the other using XPath

Answer (score 0):

You need to become best friends with String.indexOf and String.substring()

The best answer I can give you without doing it myself is to tell you to find a point with indexOf then parse it with substring

Comment: It would be better to use an existing library.  What if there was another element that appeared earlier in the XML and contained the text `en-note` in its content?

Comment: You create a second string called temp. You load all of the XML in it. You then parse it apart from top to bottom until you get what you want. Its pretty standard procedure.

Comment: IndexOf grabs the first instance of what ever you ask for so you chew apart the XML linearly until you have what you need

Comment: Ok... That's fine.  It still seems like there are libraries for this that would be more reliable.

Comment: There are but they don't handle all scenarios and I haven't found a good one that handles tags with no IDs

Comment: What about regex and groups?  I have this working using string parsing however I thought there would be a more appropriate way using an XML parser?

Comment: I have heard of Regex but I don't think it can handle large amounts of data at one time. (I could be WAY wrong on this) I was trying to parse a site at work and my friend showed me Regex and it failed with only a few hundred characters.

Comment: regex itself doesn't have any limits defined, so it must be the matcher you're using, maybe hitting a buffer issue...  I'll use the string parsing for now, thanks for your help.